# Box2d collisions (android AndEnigne)

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

I learn AndEngine and trying to make a simple game. I use physics engine box2d and need to make 2 objects in physicsworld that will be able to pass through him self and won't be able to penetrate rest of objects in this world. Is it possieble ?

Thanks in advance

Greg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, its possible using collision filters.  I think there's an example in the andengine demos